# При отправке POST-запроса выходит ошибка "Missing or invalid CSRF cookie" CakePHP 4

Tags: cookie, csrf, cakephp, middleware

Пишу на CakePHP 4.2.0

Не могу авторизоваться в админ панели из-за неправильных куки-файлов и строки CSRF которая сохраняется в куки и отправляется в форме POST-запроса. Пробовал отключать Мидлварь в **/src/Application.php**, менял функцию на другую из версий для 4.0.6 и 4.0.7, и пробовал удалять куки-файлы при входе на страницу авторизации. Ничего из этого не помогло.

Форма обратной связи с методом POST тоже не работает. Выходит такая же ошибка CSRF

сайт лежит на **поддомене**. На основном домене лежит сайт написанный на **October CMS**. Могут ли файлы куки конфликтовать из-за этого? Или для каждого поддомена куки уникальны и не пересекаются с основным доменом?

Comment: давайте подробнее с кодом, как и куда вы токен передаете и как middleware к маршрутам добавляете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была во внутренних настройках сервера, а точнее в тарифе, который был подключен. Тариф был для сайтов написанных на CMS Bitrix и сервер был настроен под него. При смене тарифа все заработало как надо

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/732156)